# Ionic 4: Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to use the cordova plugin in a new ionic 4 project  but I always run into errors regarding cordova. The plugin is properly installed and shows up in the plugin folder.

**Error**

Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-button expand="full" (click)="openLocalPdf()">Open Local PDF</ion-button>
  <ion-button expand="full" (click)="downloadAndOpenPdf()">Download and open PDF</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/File/ngx';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { DocumentViewer, DocumentViewerOptions } from '@ionic-native/document-viewer/ngx';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private file: File, private ft: FileTransfer,
              private fileOpener: FileOpener, private document: DocumentViewer, ) {

  }
  openLocalPdf() {
        const filePath = this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets';

        if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      const fakeName = Date.now();
      this.file.copyFile(filePath, '5-tools.pdf', this.file.dataDirectory, `${fakeName}.pdf`).then(result => {
        this.fileOpener.open(result.nativeURL, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
          .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
      });
    } else {
      // Use Document viewer for iOS for a better UI
      const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
        title: 'My PDF'
      };
      this.document.viewDocument(`${filePath}/5-tools.pdf`, 'application/pdf', options);
    }
  }

  downloadAndOpenPdf() {
    const downloadUrl = 'https://devdactic.com/html/5-simple-hacks-LBT.pdf';
    const path = this.file.dataDirectory;
    const transfer = this.ft.create();

    transfer.download(downloadUrl, path + 'myfile.pdf').then(entry => {
      const url = entry.toURL();

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.document.viewDocument(url, 'application/pdf', {});
      } else {
        this.fileOpener.open(url, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
          .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this using ionic serve ?

Comment: When tried using "ionic cordova run browser" got this error

" Error in SitewaertsDocumentViewer.canViewDocument():  
 Missing Command Error"

Comment: Are you using any native plugins ?

Comment: Yup it seems like. That is why I recommend going with the second option using the browser won't give you any ionic-native plugins. If that is the case you should use a device or emulator to test your app

Answer (score 17):

When you are using ionic serve you run your app as a website. So cordova won't be available. Thus leading to the error you are getting

You can bypass this in several ways.

First you could use the following to run it on the browser with cordova

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic cordova run browser
```

and run it on the browser

Second you could test this natively (or using an emulator) by issuing

```
ionic cordova platform add <ios/android>
ionic cordova run <android/ios> <--device>
```

--device if you are using a physical device or not if you intend to use an emulator.
Of course this will require the JAVA SDK, ANDROID SDK and Gradle

In the long run I would recommend to go with later since you have test the app on a native device anyway

Comment: This didn't work for me on Macbook i tried running on browse.

Comment: it worked in browser and also can run cordova file browse in browser and i can browse my files  and also camera worked here but its take more several minutes how can i restart it faster?

Comment: I get this error: native-run was not found on your PATH. Please install it globally
installing doesn't help