# Ionic 4 cordova.js not available while using ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm developing an application using `Ionic 4` and `Angular`.
I used a command to start my application on `iPhone emulator`:
`ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload`

The emulator started successfully, my app functioned, but when I tried using a function which relied on cordova plugin, it cannot be run. When I took a look in debugger console, there was a warning message:

**Native: tried calling FirebaseMessaging.getToken, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator.**

Actually, the simulator was running but I don't know why I got that error.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

P/S: I found [this topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965710/ionic-4-cordova-is-not-available-make-sure-to-include-cordova-js-or-run-in-a-d), it looks like my situation but seems like the author ran the application on web browser, not on emulator.